# Get-AzureStorageFile not listing directory contents unless I pipe it to same cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have an azure storage share called `myshare` with a structure like this:

```
/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates/File1.rdl
/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates/File2.rdl
/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates/File3.rdl
/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates/File4.rdl
```

When I try to list the files using this command

```
Get-AzureStorageFile -sharename 'myshare' -Path '3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates'
```

I just get a result listing the directory itself:

```
   Directory: https://<mystorageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/myshare/3.3.0.22

Type                Length Name    
----                ------ ----   
                         1 ReportTemplates
```

Adding a trailing / doesn't help. I'm certain this used to list the files beneath that path (as I have semi-automated steps documented including this command), but no more. Perhaps this is a change in v1.0?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806383.aspx) for Path param says

> Specifies the path of a folder. This cmdlet lists the files under the
>   folder that this parameter specifies.

And the example given suggests it should work. Same thing applies if I try to get a listing of just the `3.3.0.22` directory: I'm just given output listing the `3.3.0.22` directory itself.

I've found if I pipe the output to `Get-AzureStorageFile` (i.e. the same cmdlet again) it gives what I'd expect. But this seems wrong?

```
get-azurestoragefile -sharename 'myshare' -Path '3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates' | get-azurestoragefile


   Directory: https://<mystorageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/myshare/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates

Type                Length Name 
----                ------ ----  
                         1 File1.rdl 
                         1 File2.rdl 
                         1 File3.rdl 
                         1 File4.rdl
```

I have moved workstations since I last used these commands so it's possible there's something environmental affecting this ... but I don't know what that would be.

Running `(Get-Module -Name Azure).Version` reports version `1.0.2.-1`

Running `get-azurestoragefile -sharename 'myshare' -Path '3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates' | select-object *` gives the output below ... which feels like it's the wrong type being returned:

```
ServiceClient : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileClient
Uri           : https://<mystorageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/myshare/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates
StorageUri    : Primary = 'https://<mystorageaccount>.file.core.windows.net/myshare/3.3.0.22/ReportTemplates'; Secondary = ''
Properties    : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.FileDirectoryProperties
Metadata      : {}
Share         : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare
Parent        : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory
Name          : ReportTemplates
```

Comment: Don't have Azure but reading the docs it has to do with the parameter set you are using. Since you are specifying `-sharename` which says in docs: _Specifies the name of the file share. This cmdlet gets a __file or directory__ from the file share that this parameter specifies._.. Notice that it is not plural. That is why your second pipe does what it does. You are not using that parameter set anymore and then path works as intended.

Comment: Thanks but no, that looks like a small documentation bug.

Comment: Indeed. It led me astray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug in the current version of the Azure Powershell cmdlets. 
"Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $s -Path folderpath" should definitely return the files in the folderpath. I asked Gaurav Mantri about this, and he looked into the code, and found that the cmdlet is making a "Head" request to get the properties of the directory, and not fetching the files.

I've reported this on github, so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: That answers that then.

Comment: Thanks Robin. For anyone else interested the issue is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1543

Comment: Yeah, I know. I really needed it to work; hopefully they will fix it asap.